# Wait for future.then() completion - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having below function that should return SharedPreference instance:

```
SharedPreferences get sp {
    Future<SharedPreferences> prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    SharedPreferences temp;
    prefs.then((value) { temp = value; });
    return temp; //This is running immediately before completion and returning null 
}
```

I'm from iOS background. There is DispatchGroup to help us resolve the same issue:

```
SharedPreferences get sp {
        Future<SharedPreferences> prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        SharedPreferences temp;
        //dispatchGroup.enter()
        prefs.then((value) { 
           temp = value; 
           //dispatchGroup.leave()
        });
        //dispatchGroup.wait()
        return temp; //This is running immediately before completion 
   }
```

How can we make future.then() to wait till its completion then pass control to the next line? Is there anything similar to iOS's DispatchGroup in flutter ?

**UPDATE:**

I'm looking for a way to get SharedPreferences instance so as to use that in the example below:

```
bool get isLoggedIn => sp.getBool('IsLoggedIn');
set isLoggedIn(bool loggedIn) => sp.setBool('IsLoggedIn', loggedIn);

String get userPhone => sp.getString('UserPhone');
set userPhone(String phone) => sp.setString('UserPhone', phone);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Below is the complete class until now for managing SharedPreferences throughout the app:

```
class UserDefaults
{
  SharedPreferences sp;

  //Singleton
  UserDefaults._internal();
  static final UserDefaults _instance = UserDefaults._internal();
  factory UserDefaults() {
    _instance.initPreferences();
    return _instance;
  }

  initPreferences() async {
    sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  /*
  SharedPreferences get sp {
    Future<SharedPreferences> prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    SharedPreferences temp;
    prefs.then((value) { temp = value; });
    return temp;
  }
  */

  bool get isLoggedIn => sp.getBool('IsLoggedIn');
  set isLoggedIn(bool loggedIn) => sp.setBool('IsLoggedIn', loggedIn);

  String get userPhone => sp.getString('UserPhone');
  set userPhone(String phone) => sp.setString('UserPhone', phone);
}
```

Well this is not working when from calling UserDefaults().isLoggedIn from main() function, giving an error : 'getBool' was called on null. I guess its because initPreferences is taking some time.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code to async function:

```
SharedPreferences sp

loadPrefs() async {
    sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}

bool get isLoggedIn => sp.getBool('IsLoggedIn');
set isLoggedIn(bool loggedIn) => sp.setBool('IsLoggedIn', loggedIn);

String get userPhone => sp.getString('UserPhone');
set userPhone(String phone) => sp.setString('UserPhone', phone);
```

call loadPrefs() on init

Comment: I've tried this way. Please see the update in the question.@Vitaly

Comment: I tried this way at very first. Its not working because I guess loadPrefs() will take some time. So, my helper class named is UserDefaults which is singletone class. calling `UserDefaults().isLoggedIn` giving an error : 'The method getBool was called on null'.

Comment: you can't use async functions as sync, you should use setState when your prefs is loaded

Comment: I'll try to use setState when your prefs is loaded. Many thanks. Btw, I've included complete helper class in the question inside update2.

Comment: you can convert your methods to Future - `Future<bool> get isLoggedIn` and use `isLoggedIn().then( setState() )`

Comment: The issue was loadPrefs() called from main(). Moving that call to build() of MyApp state helped. Also I'd to pass BuildContext to loadPrefs() and so as to call `context.widget.refresh()` after `sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`. Until that splashScreen is displayed. Thanks for the trick - 'use setState when your prefs is loaded'. Upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use this:

```
Future<SharedPreferences> getSp() async{
  return await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```

Comment: Please see the update in the question. I need SharedPreferences instance so that can be used directly.

Comment: You can first get an instance of `SharedPreference` say inside `main()` function and you can then use that instance later on in your code with exactly what you asked for.